# how to send textfield data one application to another application in swift

Tags: swift

How can I share data between two apps with different ways?

Suppose I have one application that have one textfield and one button.

When I press on button in that case my textfield data send to another application.

And my first application textfield data to see to another application textfield data is it possible in swift?

Answer (score 2):

***You can share data between two apps different ways like:***

- **UIActivityViewController**

  You can send object to another app. Whatsapp etc.
- **Custom URL Schemes**

  For example you can send phone number to iOS Phone App
- **Share Extension**

  For example you can send photo from gallery to app
- **App Groups**

  You can use *app groups* to share data/files between two/more apps or containing apps.

  *This is exactly what you looking for.*
- **Shared Keychain Access**

  Enabling keychain sharing allows your app to share data in the keychain with other apps developed by your team.
- **Custom Pasteboards**

  You can share data in one place to another within your app.

**Thank's for Dinesh Kachhot for awesome article**

**Source:**

[Dinesh Kachhot's Medium Article](https://medium.com/@dinesh.kachhot/different-ways-to-share-data-between-apps-de75a0a46d4a)